# FPGA Input Signal measurement

Tags: fpga, counter, spartan, xilinx-system-generator

**How to measure input pulse signal's frequency using xilinx toolkit on matlab?**

Since I'm bad at coding,I use System generator on matlab.
I'm doing a project, In which I'll be using a Proximity sensor to measure RPM of a motor. The output of the sensor is put across Schmitt trigger, so it becomes a Pulse Signal.

I need to find the frequency of this pulse signal, So I can calculate RPM.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure frequency, you need a reference frequency you can compare it to.

The usual way to do this is to set up two counter chains, one of which is clocked by your reference frequency F<sub>ref</sub>, and the other clocked by your unknown frequency F<sub>unk</sub> (input signal conditioning is an exercise left for the student). You let the two counters run for the same amount of time T, then read their values.

$$Count_{ref} = F_{ref} \cdot T$$

$$Count_{unk} = F_{unk} \cdot T$$

Combine the two equations by dividing them, and solve for F<sub>unk</sub>:

$$F_{unk} = \frac{Count_{unk}}{Count_{ref}} F_{ref}$$

That's the general concept, but in practice, the process is often simplified by using the reference counter itself to determine the time period T, which makes Count<sub>ref</sub> a known constant, and F<sub>ref</sub> is also chosen to be a "nice round" number. This turns the multiplication and division into trivial operations, and the frequency can be read more or less directly from Count<sub>unk</sub>. For example, if F<sub>ref</sub>/Count<sub>ref</sub> = 1 Hz, then Count<sub>unk</sub> = F<sub>unk</sub> directly.

There are many subtleties associated with optimizing the performance of this process that I won't get into here, but there's one trick that's often used when you want to measure relatively low frequencies (such as RPM) with high resolution without requiring a long time T. Instead of making T depend on F<sub>ref</sub>, making Count<sub>ref</sub> constant, you make T depend on F<sub>unk</sub>, making Count<sub>unk</sub> a constant. Also, make F<sub>ref</sub> as high as you reasonably can. Now you need to do a division operation to get the answer, but you can get it in a fraction of a second with many digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Feed your pulse into the reset input of an up counter (System generator has a block for that).  Latch the output of the counter each time the pulse comes along, and feed that signal onwards.  It is a representation of frequency - knowing your FPGA's clock rate you can convert to Hz and then RPM if required, but with a little extra thought you can often work in the "clock count" domain in the next stages of your processing and avoid having to convert.